# Getting an error "allocating an object of abstract class type in Juce Framework?

Tags: c++, ios, mobile, juce

i am new in juce and getting an error like "allocating an object of abstract class type 'CreateAccount'" i am beginner in c++. i am try to call the class from the main window of juce and getting error like this.Below is my code

Main.cpp file

```
#include <JuceHeader.h>
#include "CreateAccount.h"

//==============================================================================
class TestApplication  : public JUCEApplication
{
public:
    //==============================================================================
    TestApplication() {
    }

    const String getApplicationName() override  {
        return "Test";
    }
    const String getApplicationVersion() override    { return "1.0.0"; }

    void initialise (const String&) override         {
        mainWindow.reset (new MainWindow ("Test", new CreateAccount(), *this));
     //  splash = new SplashScreen("Welcome to Screen!",ImageFileFormat::loadFrom(File("/Resources/bell.png")),
                             //    true);

       // splash->deleteAfterDelay(RelativeTime::seconds(5), false);
    }

       void shutdown() override {
        mainWindow = nullptr;
    }

private:
    class MainWindow    : public DocumentWindow
    {
    public:
        MainWindow (const String& name, Component* c, JUCEApplication& a)
                : DocumentWindow (name, Desktop::getInstance().getDefaultLookAndFeel()
                                          .findColour (ResizableWindow::backgroundColourId),
                                  DocumentWindow::allButtons),
                  app (a)
        {
            setUsingNativeTitleBar (true);
            setContentOwned (c, true);

#if JUCE_ANDROID || JUCE_IOS
            setFullScreen (true);
#else
            setResizable (true, false);
            setResizeLimits (300, 250, 10000, 10000);
            centreWithSize (getWidth(), getHeight());
#endif

            setVisible (true);
        }

        void closeButtonPressed() override
        {
            app.systemRequestedQuit();
        }


    private:
        JUCEApplication& app;


        //==============================================================================
        JUCE_DECLARE_NON_COPYABLE (MainWindow)
    };

    std::unique_ptr<MainWindow> mainWindow;


};

//==============================================================================
START_JUCE_APPLICATION (TestApplication)
```

CreateAccount.h file

```
#include <JuceHeader.h>

//new page for create profile
class CreateAccount : public Component,
                        public Button::Listener

        {
public:
    CreateAccount() {

        addAndMakeVisible(lblloginwithfb);
        lblloginwithfb.setFont(Font(18.0f));
        lblloginwithfb.setText("Login with Facebook", dontSendNotification);
        lblloginwithfb.setColour(Label::textColourId, Colours::white);

        //ready to play button
        btncreteprofile.setButtonText("Create your profile");
        btncreteprofile.setColour(TextButton::textColourOffId, Colours::white);
        btncreteprofile.setColour(TextButton::textColourOnId, Colours::white);
        btncreteprofile.setColour(TextButton::buttonColourId,  Colour::fromRGB(235,135,15));
        btncreteprofile.setColour(TextButton::buttonOnColourId, Colour::fromRGB(235,135,15));
        addAndMakeVisible(btncreteprofile);

    }
    //==============================================================================
    void paint(Graphics &g) override {
        g.fillAll(Colours::black);
    }

    void resized() override {

        /*Rectangle<int> bounds = getLocalBounds();
        FlexBox flexBox;

        flexBox.flexDirection = FlexBox::Direction::column;
        flexBox.flexWrap = FlexBox::Wrap ::noWrap;
        flexBox.alignContent = FlexBox::AlignContent::center;

        Array<FlexItem> itemarray;
        itemarray.add(FlexItem(80,50,btncreteprofile));
        itemarray.add(FlexItem(getWidth(),50,lblloginwithfb));


        flexBox.items = itemarray;
        flexBox.performLayout(bounds.removeFromBottom(200));*/
        Rectangle<int> bounds = getLocalBounds();
        const int insetX = getWidth() / 4;
        const int insetY = getHeight() / 4;


        btncreteprofile.setBounds(insetX,bounds.getCentre().y+80,getWidth() - insetX * 2, 50);
        lblloginwithfb.setBounds(insetX,insetY,getWidth() - insetX * 2,getHeight());

    }

private:
    //==============================================================================
    // Your private member variables go here...
    Label lblloginwithfb;
    TextButton btncreteprofile;

    JUCE_DECLARE_NON_COPYABLE_WITH_LEAK_DETECTOR (CreateAccount)
};
```

Please help me when i try to add the listner in createaccount file then will get an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement all pure virtual methods in `Button::Listener` to make your class not abstract. `Button::Listener` contains these two methods

```
virtual void    buttonClicked (Button *)=0
virtual void    buttonStateChanged (Button *)
```

The second method is not pure virtual, so you don't have to implement it.

So add a method to your class

```
virtual void    buttonClicked (Button *) override {}
```

and add the code needed when the button is clicked.

Depending on the C++ version you're using, the `override` might not get accepted by the compiler. In that case, just omit it. It is used to allow
the compiler to emit warnings/errors with respect to overridden methods.

Comment: Thanks a lot its working. Can you please help me how to navigation from one class to another class? for ex. I have button in one screen and when i press that button i want to open new screen like data with list in juce. I searched but did not get anything,

Comment: In your juce installation directory under `examples/ComponentTutorialExample` you'll find a Component example including PDF. The topic is too complex to describe here.

Comment: See also [the JUCE documentation](https://docs.juce.com/master/group__juce__gui__basics.html)

Comment: Hello, I have seen the example under https://github.com/DISTRHO/juce/tree/master/examples/ComponentTutorialExample link. But i did not understand how to call navigation particular for mobile (Android & iOS). Do you have any sample that use this kind of functionality? so i can understand or paste the code to do navigation between two screens. Please Help. i am learning a Juce and i am new in c++ so

Comment: i am able to call the new class on button click like this:  
if (button == &tvbtnrdytoplay) {
    removeAllChildren();           
    addAndMakeVisible (accountPage);
} but i am unable to change the color of the new screen. accountpage is the class object. My first screen contains yellow background and second screen contain black. so all are working fine but not able to hide the yellow background color instead of black.

Comment: You're removing the children of your accountpage. To fully replace the content, you have to use `setContentOwned()` or `setContentNonOwned()` on your `MainWindow`, as you already did according to the code above. Managing the life cycle of the objects is usually not automatic in C++. There's more than one way to get a pointer/reference to the `MainWindow` to your content view, either in the constructor or as a setter and you need an instance variable on all your Component's.

Comment: I have take an example and change the only my components as per my requirement. can you please how to call the setContentOwned() in other class? if you share code example the its batter

Answer (score 2):

In JUCE, most UI related things are implemented as a subclass of Component.

Some of the subclasses have the concept of a content component: all subclasses
of `ResizableWindow`, which adds the `setContentOwned()` and `setContentNonOwned()`
methods, inherited by all subclasses of `ResizableWindow` (especially
`DocumentWindow`).

To define the content of the `DocumentWindow`, the example code in your question
uses `setContentOwned()` in the `MainWindow` constructor which it gets from the
`initialise()` in `TestApplication`.

To implement the navigation you could do the following (there are other ways to do it):

#### 1. Implement the navigation in the `MainWindow`, so you have the navigation logic in  one central place

#### 2. Give each of your "Pages" (let's call one step a Page.) a pointer to the `MainWindow`. For `CreateAccount` that would be

CreateAccount.h file:

```
void setMainWindow(MainWindow * _mainWindow)
{
  mainWindow = _mainWindow;
}
```

#### 3. Add an instance variable, too, somewhere in the `CreateAccount` class:

```
MainWindow * mainWindow;
```

and update the constructor:

```
CreateAccount()
  : mainWindow(nullptr)
{
  // ...
}
```

#### 4. Change the creation code

replace

```
mainWindow.reset (new MainWindow ("Test", new CreateAccount(), *this));
```

by:

```
CreateAccount * ca = new CreateAccount();
MainWindow * mw = new MainWindow ("Test", ca, *this)
ca->setMainWindow(mw);
mainWindow.reset(mw);
```

#### 5. Implement your navigation in a set of custom methods (need to be public) in `MainWindow`, e.g.

```
public:
void createProfileClicked()
{
   // ...get entered data...
   // ...process entered data...
   // ...implement next navigation step...
   // (you would create or recycle the "Page" for the next step here)
   setContentOwned(
     // ...
   );
}
```

#### 6. Call that method from the `buttonClicked()` event handler in `CreateAccount`:

```
mainWindow->createProfileClicked();
```

This is just one way to implement what you want. It all depends on the complexity of your project.

---

Edit:

My suggestion given in this answer introduces cyclic dependencies of classes.

Let me first restate what I think you currently have, deduced from your comments:

mainwindow.h

```
#include "splashpage.h"

class MainWindow : public DocumentWindow
{
public:
    // ...

    void alaramReadyBtnClicked()
    {
        setContentOwned(new SplashPage(), false);
    }

    // ...
};
```

splashpage.h:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

class SplashPage : public Component, public Button::Listener
{
public:
    SplashPage()
        : mainWindow(nullptr)
    {}

    void setMainWindow(MainWindow * _mainWindow)
    { mainWindow = _mainWindow; }

    void buttonClicked (Button *) override
    {
        if (button == &tvbtnSomething) {
            mainWindow->splashSomethingClicked();
        }
    }

private:
    MainWindow * mainWindow;
};
```

There's a cyclic dependency of declarations in there between `MainWindow` and the Page classes. When the compiler sees

```
mainWindow->splashSomethingClicked();
```

it needs to have seen the declaration of `MainWindow` but in `mainwindow.h`
it needs the declaration of `SplashPage` for this:

```
void alaramReadyBtnClicked()
{
    setContentOwned(new SplashPage(), false);
}
```

First, it is good practice to use include guards in your header files

e.g. mainwindow.h

```
// you need these include guards to prevent that the compiler
// sees this file a second time; it's a very good rule of thumb to always do this
// in you header files

#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include "splashpage.h"

class MainWindow : public DocumentWindow
{
    // ...
};

#endif // !defined(MAINWINDOW_H)
```

There are specific situations in C++ for which the compiler doesn't need to know the complete declaration: if you only use pointers or references and don't reference them. You can then use a forward declaration of class names.

But you can't do this with everything in header files only. Because there's a concept of a "compilation unit".

To break the cyclic dependency, change your ...Page.h:

```
#ifndef SPLASHPAGE_H
#define SPLASHPAGE_H

// don't include mainwindow.h here

class MainWindow; // forward declaration


class SplashPage : public Component, public Button::Listener
{
public:
    SplashPage()
        : mainWindow(nullptr)
    {}

    void setMainWindow(MainWindow * _mainWindow)
    {
        mainWindow = _mainWindow; // pointer copy does not need full declaration
    }

    // note: implementation not in this header file anymore
    void buttonClicked (Button *) override;

private:
    // ...
    MainWindow * mainWindow; // does not need full declaration
};

#endif // !defined(SPLASHPAGE_H)
```

splashpage.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "splashpage.h"

void SplashPage::buttonClicked (Button *) override
{
    if (button == &tvbtnSomething) {
        mainWindow->splashSomethingClicked();
    }
}
```

If you use the JUCE Projucer tool, you can add pairs of these files easily which should already contain the include guards stuff.

[image]

Comment: @Google: You could use a [DrawableButton](https://docs.juce.com/master/classDrawableButton.html) and do the handling as I wrote here.

Comment: I used your way for navgation and its working fine for single screen. i have created void alaramReadyBtnClicked(){
         setContentOwned (new SpalshPage(), false);
     } this function in MainWindow class. I have included Spalshpage in mainwindow class at top of screen #include "SpalshPage.h". Now when i go in SpaslhPage and try to create object of mainwindw then it give me error: MainWindow * mainWindow; Can not resolve type MainWindow. But when i remove the class import from MainWindow.h file then its working perfect. can you please help me where i am stuck?

Comment: I edited my answer with info about breaking cyclic dependencies which has nothing directly to do with JUCE. I hope this helps.

Comment: can you please come on chat. i want to discuss more please. here is the SO link.  https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211195/room-for-google-and-rpress

Comment: Hello Can you please help me in topic? can we start chat over stackoverflow or somewhere? Please send me your best way for communication.

Comment: do have any idea regarding this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61379818/how-to-set-the-icon-at-bottom-of-the-screen-in-single-row-in-juce

Comment: i have done navigation as per your code. but in some screen i got an error in android devices like below:  Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xe0 in tid 4757 (ompany.pitchbop) how to solve this error?